# Specific discrete system $x_n = A(n,u)\cdot x_{n-1}$ control papers

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, textbook-recommendation

Basic discrete control theory mostly studies systems which can be represented as $x_n=A(n)x_{n-1}+B(n)u_n$.

I wonder if optimal control of specific discrete systems of the type $x_n = A(n,u)\cdot x_{n-1}$ have been described in any paper?

Or maybe there is a control theory handbook where different systems and their presumed control are listed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are willing to consider the special case that $A(n,u)$ is linear in control $u$, then this becomes a bilinear control system (see for example, [the book by David Elliott](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9781402096129?token=prtst0416p)), for which optimal  control results have appeared in literature.

Comment: Thanks, this is the closest to my interest. Do you know any possible references for "bi-nonlinear" control?

Comment: I do not know any such references.